# convert comma separated command line arguments to json in shell script

Tags: linux, shell

I'm using below script to generate json data from comma separated values to feed zabbix.
but i'm getting one extra comma symbol. please try to optimize the comma in the end line.

```
#/bin/bash
IFS=':, ' read -r -a array <<< "$1"
idx=0
echo {\"data\":[
while [ -n "${array[$idx]}" ]; do
        echo -n \{\"{#R_IP}\":\""${array[$idx]}"\"}
        let idx=$idx+1
        [ -n "$array[idx]}" ] && echo "," || echo
done
echo ]}
exit
```

input

```
./test.sh embimsrv.exe,emcms.exe,emcmsg.exe,emforecastsrv.exe,emgtw.exe,emguisrv.exe,emmaintag.exe,emselfservicesrv.exe,Naming_Service.exe,p_ctmce.exe,p_ctmcs.exe,p_ctmrt.exe,p_ctmtr.exe,p_ctmwd.exe
```

output

```
{"data":[
{"{#R_IP}":"embimsrv.exe"},
{"{#R_IP}":"emcms.exe"},
{"{#R_IP}":"emcmsg.exe"},
{"{#R_IP}":"emforecastsrv.exe"},
{"{#R_IP}":"emgtw.exe"},
{"{#R_IP}":"emguisrv.exe"},
{"{#R_IP}":"emmaintag.exe"},
{"{#R_IP}":"emselfservicesrv.exe"},
{"{#R_IP}":"Naming_Service.exe"},
{"{#R_IP}":"p_ctmce.exe"},
{"{#R_IP}":"p_ctmcs.exe"},
{"{#R_IP}":"p_ctmrt.exe"},
{"{#R_IP}":"p_ctmtr.exe"},
{"{#R_IP}":"p_ctmwd.exe"},
]}
```

Comment: Comma separation is really the wrong way to do it. The shell (the one run by the user invoking your script, not the one running the script itself) splits command line arguments on whitespace, honoring its quoting rules; when you pass a comma-separated list, that doesn't stop the shell from doing its own splitting and other handling first.

Comment: ...hand-generating JSON, is *also* the wrong way to do it; you have way more bugs than the missing comma. Use a real JSON generation tool/library and your code won't breaking moment you're injecting data with characters that need to be escaped to be valid in JSON strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Manually piecing together JSON like this is pretty brittle. But here goes. A very common trick is to *prefix* each string except the first with a comma.

```
#!/bin/bash
IFS=':, ' read -r -a array <<< "$1"
prefix=''
printf '%s' '{"data":['
for item in "${array[@]}"; do
    printf '%s%s' "$prefix" "{\"{#R_IP}\":\"$item\"}"
    prefix=','
done
printf '%s\n' ']}'
```

Notice also how no explicit `exit` is required at the end of a script. The shell stops executing the script and terminates when it reaches the end of the script.

Also, the shebang needs to start with exactly the two single-byte characters `#!`.

Finally, a much better overall design is probably to not require the arguments to be comma-separated; but I won't try to fix that here.

Comment: One simplification(?): move the fixed part of the object into the first argument of `printf`, like so: `printf '%s{"{#R_IP}": "%s"}' "$prefix" "$item"`. It doesn't work any better (or worse) this way, but does provide a cleaner separation between the static and dynamic parts of the generated JSON.

Comment: A warning to the OP: make sure to take note of Charles Duffy's second comment on the question.

Answer (score 8):

Use a proper tool, like [`jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/), to generate your JSON.

```
printf '%s' "$1" | jq -R 'split(",") | map({"{#R_IP}": .}) | {data: .}'
```

Comment: I'm out of votes for today, but for the record, this gets my upvote too, once I can.